# SQL Developer não executa no Ubuntu

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, sqldeveloper

Estou tentando executar o Oracle SQL Developer no Ubuntu e quando chega na parte da imagem abaixo a execução fica presa.

[image: problema com instalação]

Procurei na internet mas não encontrei nada que pudesse me ajudar. Alguém já teve esse problema?

Teoricamente deveria aparecer a tela abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Deculpe, não me preocupei com a formatação, na verdade minha preocupação era apenas uma resposta para um problema.

Comment: Qual a versão do Ubuntu? Para instalar o Oracle SQL Developer 17.3 deve antes instalar o Java JDK 8 e somente após o Oracle SQL Developer. Vide http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev-relnotes-173-3939064.html

Comment: Versão 16.04, sql developer 17.3.1. Instalei o java JDK 8 antes de realizar a instalação do sql.

Comment: Essa versão do Oracle SQL Developer, 17.3, é recente. Talvez por causa disso ainda não existam tutoriais específicos para instalação do Oracle SQL Developer 17.3 no Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 2):

Para utilizar o Oracle SQL Developer 17.3, deve-se antes instalar o Java Development Kit (JDK) 8, conforme consta na página [Oracle SQL Developer 17.3 Release Notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev-relnotes-173-3939064.html). Nessa documentação também é citado que *If SQL Developer cannot find a local JDK, you will be prompted to enter the location path for the JDK. Note that the prompt wants only the folder, not the java.exe*.

Na primeira vez que o Oracle SQL Developer é executado, ele solicita onde está instalado o JDK: `Type the full pathname of a JDK installation`. Uma forma de obter a denominação completa é abrir uma sessão de terminal e executar os seguintes comandos:

```
cd /usr/lib/jvm
ls
```

A resposta do último comando varia de acordo com o JDK instalado (Oracle JDK ou OpenJDK). No caso de instalação padrão do Ubuntu pode ser algo como

```
default-java    java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64     java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

Informe então o seguinte full pathname:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

Referências:

- [SQL Developer Documentation Release 17.3](https://docs.oracle.com/database/sql-developer-17.3/)
- [Install SQL Developer on Ubuntu](https://www.dizwell.com/wordpress/technical-articles/oracle/install-sql-developer-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: procurei reinstalar o JDK segundo seu comentário e funcionou perfeitamente. Segui esse link para reinstalar a JDK https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/Instalacao-e-Configuracao-do-JDK-7?pagina=3 mudando logicamente apenas a versão.

Comment: estou com outra situação. Durante a instalação o SQL developer não perguntou usuário e senha. Nesse caso não consigo logar, existe algum usuário padrão ou algum jeito de configurar um usuário
?

Comment: Usuário e senha referem-se à conexão com o banco de dados. Sugiro que crie outro tópico específico, pois é um assunto diferente; isto é, não tem referência com a instalação mas sim diretamente com o banco de dados ao qual deseja se conectar.

Comment: Ok. Obrigado pela ajuda.